# What is the unit in /sys/devices/system/node/node0/distance

Tags: linux, sys, numa

The question says on the title. Does anyone know what the distance represent in this sys file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This distance is a number which is relative to all of the other distances.

Comment: Thank for the answer. I can also guess it's relative to the other socket's distance, but what exactly is the number's unit? Is it the IPI latency. something else? If it's simply for relative distance, I was wondering why it's not starting with 1.

Comment: I'd guess it's got more to do with something like hops (via HT/QPI) than anything else.  Redhat's release notes claimed it was merely relative and didn't cite units.